# wicket modal window error on close

Tags: wicket, modal-window, confirm-dialog

**Sometimes** when closing ModalWindow the message "Do you want to leave or stay ..." pop up.
I am not able to determine why. For instance, I close window 10x (still in the same way) and some of these tries end up with this failure.
It would be ok, but parent page is constructed again and all data are lost, which is not user-friendly.

My project specification:

- Wicket: 6.21.0
- Java: 8
- Spring: 4.1.1.RELEASE
- and other (I hope not relevant dependencies)

What I have done, tried or explore so far:

- when modal window is closed and error occur, the parent Page is constructed again
- when error occurs, no close callback is called
- modalWindow.showUnloadConfirmation(false) - doesn't work. Confirm window doesn't show up, but when window is closed, parent page is reloaded and data are gone
- update of wicket to latest 6.24 version or Spring 4.1.6 doesn't help
- downgrade to wicket 6.1.9 didn't help
- upgrade to wicket 7.4 didn't help
- when error **NOT** occurs, ModalWindow Page is for example generated by http 8443 exec 5 thread and **callback** is **caught** by the **same thread**
- when error occurs, ModalWindow Page is for example generated by http 8443 exec **5** thread, but when fails and new parent Page is created by http 8443 exec **9** thread for example
- also didn't help to add close button and before calling window.close() to clear and detach all dataproviders
- when modal window fails, window.close() method in javascript is the last thing, that is called. No code after that is called. After that comes probably redirect to parent page (that's why the Do you want to leave this page confirm dialog).
- all above can be tested by creating new Java class, that extends ModalWindow and override protected method String getCloseJavacript(), which returns closing JavaScript code in form of String.

**SOLUTION**

The problem was when the parent page loaded data, the page size was to big to be stored into Wicket page caching memory. Therefore, when the modal window was closed, the saved parent page supposed to be loaded, but it was never saved, therefore new was generated. The size of Wicket page caching memory, can be set in WicketApplication class. More at https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/versioningCaching.html in section Page caching.

Answer (score 0):

This is configurable: use ModalWindow#showUnloadConfirmation(boolean) to control it.

Comment: I have tried, see the 3rd bullet. The information message is not so important. What I am much more care is fact that the parent page is created again.

Comment: Then the issue is in your application code. It is hard to guess what it is exactly.